# pandas sorting pivot_table or grouping dataframe?

Tags: python, sorting, pandas, pivot

I have a problem. I did this:

```
In [405]: pippo=ass_t1.pivot_table(['Rotazioni a volume','Distribuzione Ponderata'],rows=['SEGM1','DESC']).sort()

In [406]: pippo
Out[406]: 
                      Distribuzione Ponderata  Rotazioni a volume
SEGM1 DESC                                                       
AD     ACCADINAROLO                    74.040       140249.693409
      ZYMIL AMALAT Z                   90.085       321529.053570
FUN   SPECIALMALAT S                   88.650       120711.182177
NORM   STD INNAROLO                    49.790       162259.216710
       STD P.NAROLO                    52.125      1252174.695695
       STD PLNAROLO                    54.230       213257.829615
      BONTA' MALAT B                   79.280       520454.366419
      DA STD RILGARD                   35.290       554927.497875
      OVANE VT.MANTO                   15.040       466232.639628
      WEIGHT MALAT W                   79.170       118628.572692
```

My goal is to have each 'SEGM1' sorted by 'Distribuzione Ponderata'. E.g. in 'NORM' subset the first row should be "BONTA' MALAT B" with the higher level of 'Distribuzione Ponderata'.
I was able to achieve partially the result using groupby method but without being able to set multiple columns.
Someone can help me please?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
import io
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

text = '''\
SEGM1\tDESC\tDistribuzione Ponderata\tRotazioni a volume
AD\tACCADINAROLO\t74.040\t140249.693409
AD\tZYMIL AMALAT Z\t90.085\t321529.053570
FUN\tSPECIALMALAT S\t88.650\t120711.182177
NORM\tSTD INNAROLO\t49.790\t162259.216710
NORM\tSTD P.NAROLO\t52.125\t1252174.695695
NORM\tSTD PLNAROLO\t54.230\t213257.829615
NORM\tBONTA' MALAT B\t79.280\t520454.366419
NORM\tDA STD RILGARD\t35.290\t554927.497875
NORM\tOVANE VT.MANTO\t15.040\t466232.639628
NORM\tWEIGHT MALAT W\t79.170\t118628.572692
'''

df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(text), delimiter = '\t',
                 index_col = (0,1),)

key1 = df.index.labels[0]
key2 = df['Distribuzione Ponderata'].rank(ascending=False)
sorter = np.lexsort((key2, key1))

sorted_df = df.take(sorter)
print(sorted_df)
```

yields

```
                      Distribuzione Ponderata  Rotazioni a volume
SEGM1 DESC                                                       
AD    ZYMIL AMALAT Z                   90.085       321529.053570
      ACCADINAROLO                     74.040       140249.693409
FUN   SPECIALMALAT S                   88.650       120711.182177
NORM  BONTA' MALAT B                   79.280       520454.366419
      WEIGHT MALAT W                   79.170       118628.572692
      STD PLNAROLO                     54.230       213257.829615
      STD P.NAROLO                     52.125      1252174.695695
      STD INNAROLO                     49.790       162259.216710
      DA STD RILGARD                   35.290       554927.497875
      OVANE VT.MANTO                   15.040       466232.639628
```

I learned this trick [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10606901/190597). The key idea is to use [numpy.lexsort](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.lexsort.html#numpy-lexsort).