# Rearranging order in Pivot Table

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have the follwing pivot table in pandas:

```
   Division             BU/CF        Allocation Key CurrentHC 

0  Central Functions     A            NEF           3 
1                        B            NEF           2 
2                        C            EXP           1 
3                                     NEF           4 
4                        D            NEF           3 
5  Xerxes                E            NLE           4 
6                        F            NLE           1 
7                        G            NLE           1 
8                        H            NLE           5
```

Python obviously sorts the division and BU/CF alphabetically. How can I apply my own order to the pivot table.

Desired output:

```
   Division              BU/CF       Allocation Key CurrentHC 
0  Central Functions     D            NEF           3 
1                        B            NEF           2 
2                        C            EXP           1 
3                                     NEF           4 
4                        A            NEF           3 
5  Xerxes                E            NLE           4 
6                        H            NLE           5 
7                        G            NLE           1 
8                        F            NLE           1
```

Code I used to create the pivot table:

```
#Create full report pivot 
report_pivot = pd.pivot_table(full_report, index=["Division","BU/CF", "Allocation Key"], 
                       values=["Previous HC", "New Hire", "Resigned", "In", "Out", "Current HC", "Delta"], 

                       fill_value=0)
```

I managed to rearrange the columns by doing this:

```
# Reorderr columns 
cols = [ "Previous HC", "New Hire", "Resigned", "In", "Out","Delta", "Current HC"] 
report_pivot = report_pivot[cols]
```

Is there a similar way for the index. Specifically "BU/CF"

*I excluded the other columns except for Current HC to simplify in the tables above

Comment: Maybe thatone helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10595327/pandas-sort-pivot-table   Please give a complete code and data so that we can easily adapt a solution.

Comment: I added the code I used to make the pivot table

Comment: looking at your desired DF it's absolutely not clear what means `my own order`. Can you define the sort criterias?

Comment: Okay, for the division Xerxes for example in "BU/CF" the order is alphabetical: [E, F, G, H]. I would like to the order to be like this: [E,H,G,F]. There are no criterias on how to sort it, the order I want is decided by me. I hope I could make it clear now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well you can do something like this:

```
In [62]: sort_map = {
   ....:  'E': 10,
   ....:  'H': 20,
   ....:  'G': 30,
   ....:  'F': 40,
   ....: }

In [63]: df.loc[df['Division'] == 'Xerxes', 'BU/CF'].map(sort_map)
Out[63]:
5    10
6    40
7    30
8    20
Name: BU/CF, dtype: int64

In [64]: idx = df.loc[df['Division'] == 'Xerxes', 'BU/CF'].map(sort_map).sort_values().index

In [65]: idx
Out[65]: Int64Index([5, 8, 7, 6], dtype='int64')

In [66]: df[df['Division'] == 'Xerxes'].reindex(idx)
Out[66]:
  Division BU/CF AllocationKey  CurrentHC
5   Xerxes     E           NLE          4
8   Xerxes     H           NLE          5
7   Xerxes     G           NLE          1
6   Xerxes     F           NLE          1
```

---

**UPDATE:**

starting from Pandas 0.20.1 [the .ix indexer is deprecated, in favor of the more strict .iloc and .loc indexers](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#deprecate-ix).