# Sorting pivot table (multi index)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, sorting, numpy, pivot-table

I'm trying to sort a pivot table's values in descending order after putting two "row labels" (Excel term) on the pivot.

sample data:

```
x = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['a','a','b','c','c', 'a','b','c', 'a','b','c'],
                  'col2':[  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,   2,  2,  2,   3,  3,  3],
                  'col3':[  1,.67,0.5,  2,.65, .75,2.25,2.5, .5,  2,2.75]})
print(x)
   col1  col2  col3
0     a     1  1.00
1     a     1  0.67
2     b     1  0.50
3     c     1  2.00
4     c     1  0.65
5     a     2  0.75
6     b     2  2.25
7     c     2  2.50
8     a     3  0.50
9     b     3  2.00
10    c     3  2.75
```

To create the pivot, I'm using the following function:

```
pt = pd.pivot_table(x, index = ['col1', 'col2'], values = 'col3', aggfunc = np.sum)
print(pt)
           col3
col1 col2      
a    1     1.67
     2     0.75
     3     0.50
b    1     0.50
     2     2.25
     3     2.00
c    1     2.65
     2     2.50
     3     2.75
```

In words, this variable `pt` is first sorted by `col1`, then by values of `col2` within `col1` then by `col3` within all of those. This is great, but I would like to sort by `col3` (the values) while keeping the groups that were broken out in `col2` (this column can be any order and shuffled around).

The target output would look something like this (`col3` in descending order with any order in `col2` with that group of `col1`):

```
                   col3
    col1   col2    
     a       1     1.67
             2     0.75
             3     0.50

     b       2     2.25
             3     2.00 
             1     0.50

     c       3     2.75
             1     2.65
             2     2.50
```

I have tried the code below, but this just sorts the entire pivot table values and loses the grouping (I'm looking for sorting within the group).

```
    pt.sort_values(by = 'col3', ascending = False)
```

For guidance, a similar question was asked (and answered) here, but I was unable to get a successful output with the provided output:

[Pandas: Sort pivot table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10595327/pandas-sort-pivot-table)

The error I get from that answer is `ValueError: all keys need to be the same shape`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for `DataFrame`, then [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) by `col1` and `col3` and last [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) for `MultiIndex`:

```
df = df.reset_index()
       .sort_values(['col1','col3'], ascending=[True, False])
       .set_index(['col1','col2'])

print (df)
           col3
col1 col2      
a    1     1.67
     2     0.75
     3     0.50
b    2     2.25
     3     2.00
     1     0.50
c    3     2.75
     1     2.65
     2     2.50
```