# Sort a 2 index pivot table: values within group, index based on values

Tags: pandas, sorting, pivot-table

I have a dataframe like this:

```
x = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['bul', 'eng','eng', 'ger','ger', 'fra','fra'],
                  'col2':['fra', 'ger','fra', 'fra','eng', 'ger','eng'],
                  'col3':[    1,     4,    2,     6,    7,    20,    5]})
pt = pd.pivot_table(x, index = ['col1', 'col2'], values = 'col3', aggfunc = np.sum)
pt
           col3
col1 col2      
bul  fra      1
eng  fra      2
     ger      4
fra  eng      5
     ger     20
ger  eng      7
     fra      6
```

which I want to sort to arrive at:

```
           col3
col1 col2      
fra  ger     20
     eng      5
ger  eng      7
     fra      6
eng  ger      4
     fra      2
bul  fra      1
```

the third column sorted descendingly (within col1 cell) and col1 sorted based on a property of col3, *here max (20 > 7 > 4 > 1)*

There are several questions dealing with similar problems, mine is relevant because it features a descriptive title and sample data (also other questions answers don't work for me)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/45300480/3014199 suggests

```
df = pt.reset_index()
       .sort_values(['col1','col3'], ascending=[True, False])
       .set_index(['col1','col2'])

print(df)
           col3
col1 col2      
bul  fra      1
eng  fra      2
     ger      4
fra  eng      5
ger  fra      6
     eng      7
fra  ger     20
```

Which seems to sort col3 for the dataFrame there, but doesn't seem to work at all for my data.

[Pandas: Sort pivot table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10595327/pandas-sort-pivot-table) seems promising as well, but like others I get `ValueError: all keys need to be the same shape`

**Update:**
My example was not general enough, sorry! It should also work if 2 groups share the same max, e.g.

```
x2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['bul', 'eng','eng', 'ger','ger', 'fra','fra'],
                   'col2':['fra', 'ger','fra', 'fra','eng', 'ger','eng'],
                   'col3':[    1,     7,    2,     6,    7,    20,    5]})
```

E.g. MaxU's solution yields:

```
           col3
col1 col2           
fra  ger   20 
     eng   5  
ger  eng   7  
eng  ger   7  
ger  fra   6  
eng  fra   2  
bul  fra   1
```

I bet adding a hash(or rather a grouping number divided by 10) of col1 to the 'max' would work, but there has to be a better way...
Yes! This seems to work:

```
pt['New']=pt.groupby(level='col1').col3.transform('max')
pt['New'] = 1/(pt.index.labels[0]+1)+pt['New'].values
pt=pt.sort_values(['New','col3'],ascending=False).drop('New',1)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can using a new para to achieve this

```
pt['New']=pt.groupby(level='col1').col3.transform('max')
pt=pt.sort_values(['New','col3'],ascending=False).drop('New',1)
pt
Out[1445]: 
           col3
col1 col2      
fra  ger     20
     eng      5
ger  eng      7
     fra      6
eng  ger      4
     fra      2
bul  fra      1
```

Updated :

```
pt['New']=pt.groupby(level='col1').col3.transform('max')
pt['New1']=pt.groupby(level='col1').col3.ngroup()
pt=pt.sort_values(['New','New1','col3'],ascending=False)


pt
Out[151]: 
           col3  New  New1
col1 col2                 
fra  ger     20   20     2
     eng      5   20     2
ger  eng      7    7     3
     fra      6    7     3
eng  ger      7    7     1
     fra      2    7     1
bul  fra      1    1     0
```

Comment: I just tried this on different data(replaced 4 with 7) and it doesn't work if 2 groups' max are equal. See appendix to my question.

Comment: wait! in `sort_values` we still need 'col3' -> `sort_values(['New','New1','col3']...`

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution very similar to Wen's which uses `set_index`, `sort_index` and `reset_index`:

```
In [188]: (pt.set_index([pt.groupby(level='col1').col3.transform('max'), pt['col3']], append=True)
     ...:    .sort_index(level=[2,3], ascending=False)
     ...:    .reset_index(level=[2,3], drop=True)
     ...: )
     ...:
Out[188]:
           col3
col1 col2
fra  ger     20
     eng      5
ger  eng      7
     fra      6
eng  ger      4
     fra      2
bul  fra      1
```

Comment: That is not yet what I need, col3 should be descending but here 5 is over 20 and 7 is over 6. I tried to fiddle with `ascending` but I can't fix it on my own

Comment: You also get a heads-up: your solution assumes that the max are all unique, but they are not necessarily. see update to my question